# How to write regex that matches string from begining to first new line occurence?

Tags: c#, regex

how to match string from beginning to first new line feed.

Example if TextBox1.Text value is

> 'START: Milestone One\r\nFirst milestone is achieved in a week.'

Here is what I am trying:-

```
TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(TestBox1.Text, @"START: \w+\s?", "");
```

This Regex is finding first word only therefore replacing 'START: MileStone' with string.empty but leaving 'One' there.

I need to replace everything (including newline feed) before first newline feed.

Comment: `var lines = "Milestone One\r\nFirst milestone is achieved in a week".Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a regex for that, just use `IndexOf('\n') + 1`:

```
var t = "START: Milestone One\r\nFirst milestone is achieved in a week.";
Console.WriteLine(t.Substring(t.IndexOf('\n') + 1).Trim());
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/zhuhG5)

Result: `First milestone is achieved in a week.`

A regex will not be efficient here, but you can check it for yourself:

```
var text = Regex.Replace(t, @"(?>.+\r?\n)\s*", string.Empty);
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/EFxJbE)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what happens if `t` is null or if the new line character isn't present.

Comment: @Erik: I do not think `t` can be null, it is `TextBox.Text`, I think it is always `string.Empty`. But perhaps... And if `\n` is not present, just the original string will be returned.

Comment: I get that. I thought that a mention that null checking should occur or an exception would be thrown could be useful to future readers. Likewise I thought it would be nice to explicitly state what would happen if the new-line char wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ:

```
string str = "START: Milestone One\r\nFirst milestone is achieved in a week.";

string newStr = String.Join("", str.SkipWhile(c => c != '\n').Skip(1));

Console.WriteLine(newStr); // First milestone is achieved in a week.
```

To check if the input string is null or contains any `\n`:

```
string newStr = (str?.Any(c => c == '\n')).GetValueOrDefault() ? String.Join("", str.SkipWhile(c => c != '\n').Skip(1)) : str;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your anything like me but maybe you are practicing Regex and want to know how to make it happen with it.  I'm very new at coding but I took your example and this is how I would make it happen.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = "START: Milestone One\r\nFirst milestone is achieved in a week.";

        string final = Regex.Replace(test, ".*\\n", "START: ").ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(final); // START: First milestone is achieved in a week.
    }
```

Not sure if that helps your or not but thought I would try. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing your regex:

```
[\w\s]+\n
```

you might need to play with \n and \r a bit. [\w\s] is equivalent to . so `.*\n` will do the job as well

Yours didn't work as you stopped at first whitespace, while you want to replace any word or whitespace until the linefeed, as far as I can understand.